# w3m unix encoding latin accents

Tags: linux, unix, text, html, w3m

im trying to get only text from a webpage using terminal, but im having problems with latin accents like 'áéíóú'.

im using

w3m -dump https://www.revistavirtualpro.com/noticias/energia

but if you try the code you can see that in some words are missing characters wher it is suposed to be latin characters like "á é í ó ú".

can anyone please help me with this?

thanks!

Comment: `-dump` doesn't give you any of the metadata that HTTP includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using links -dump https://www.revistavirtualpro.com/noticias/energia